# One keyboard key not working

Tags: laptop-repair

One keyboard key not working properly after I opened my laptop to clean ant infestation . I have tried blowing air to clean it still no use. Nine key is not working. It works randomly sometimes that too If I click it continuously it won't work. I don't it is virus because I have dual boot Linux same thing there also. I am tensed that I may have damaged motherboard accidently while opening.
Guys can you please let me know is it problem in keyboard or other critical component?

New Update:
I removed keycap

[image]

When I press that white rubber thing that key works fine but when put keycap problem starts again. Guys please let me know the solution.

Comment: I've cropped & sharpened your image as much as I could, but there's not really sufficient detail to see what's happened. You may have broken the keycap's mechanism. I'd suggest swapping it with another key & see what happens - but note that if you broke one, it will be really easy to break another.

Comment: I have swapped no use.

Comment: Then it's probably time for a new keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you damaged it when you were cleaning it.

The same issue on two different OSes says it's a hardware fail.

You could try cleaning it with contact cleaner, but it may require a new keyboard; impossible to tell without seeing it in person.

Comment: Only one key not working. Can you say is it keyboard or other component

Comment: It's the switch on the keyboard. If you'd broken the track, you would probably have lost more keys, in a diagonal line.

Comment: Only one key. I haven't lost more keys I have checked. nine in top

Answer (score 0):

As an amateur at taking apart laptops, I have had similar issues where some or many keys will stop working after taking the machine apart. The culprit in my case is a poor connection between the keyboard and your laptop's motherboard. Dealing with ribbon cables can be difficult, and it is possible that the connection is just loose enough to disable one of your keys.

I would suggest removing the keyboard, disconnecting and reconnecting the ribbon cable (ensuring the connection is snug), and then testing each of the keys before reconnecting the keyboard.

Comment: I have done that. i also tried cleaning the ribbon.

Comment: Did your laptop had similar symptoms like randomly working sometimes and problem in only one key .Cuz thinking of giving another try

Comment: @nb6R7 The problem was typically across multiple keys, but if you've removed and replaced the ribbon I find it highly unlikely that it would still be just the 9 key that is affected.This may not be the answer you're looking for.